# hibernate projections doesnt get only desired column

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to use projections to fetch only one column (countColumn) from a table. But somehow it's returning me the complete database row (meaning all the columns for the unique record from table). Please help me to identify what's the fix. Thanks in advance.

code:

```
final String queryCount = "from DomainObj objShortName where objShortName.field1=:field1";
HibernateCallback hibernateCallback = new HibernateCallback(){
     public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryCount);
        query.setParameter("field1", field1);
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DomainObject.class, "domainObj");
        ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
        proList.add(Projections.property("objShortName.countColumn")); //countColumn is parameted defined in my domain bean which is for countColumn in database table.
        criteria.setProjection(proList);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DomainObject.class));

        return query.list();
    }
};
```

Comment: Why you are mixing the criteria API and the Query API?

Comment: @AVolpe you mean I should be just using " Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DomainObject.class, "domainObj"); ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();       proList.add(Projections.property("objShortName.countColumn"));         criteria.setProjection(proList);" and get the result using statement criteria.list() ?? does it fire select query on table autimatically and fetch me the list?  thanks for your response..

Comment: yes, but you have a Criteria, and dont get the result of your code, you don't mix the two aproaches, just use one, `select o.countColumn from DomainObj o where o.field1 =: field1`

Answer (score 0):

You can't select an entity and project fields back to the same entity object. You need to use a non-entity DTO, which has a constructor taking the projected values.

Remove the result transformer:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DomainObject.class));
```

And simply extract the projected values like this:

```
List results = criteria.list();
for(Object result : results) {
    Object[] data = (Object[]) result;
    Number countColumn = data[0];
    ...
}
```